# Provide custom logic for failed authorization from OKTA (React SDK)

Tags: reactjs, okta

I'm using the React OKTA library, trying to better handle a "failed authorization" case within my app and can't figure out a way to do so.  My code is roughly as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Security, LoginCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';

const config = {
  // Configuration here
};
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(config);

const CALLBACK_PATH = '/implicit/callback';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth}>
          <Route path={CALLBACK_PATH} component={LoginCallback} />
      </Security>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default App;
```

In order for my authentication/authorization to pass, a user needs a valid username/password combo, along with access to a specified group.  Things are configured properly on the OKTA side since I can only get in when I have a valid username/password combo, along with access to the specific group.  When I attempt to log in with a valid username/password combo but WITHOUT the required group, I'm left on what appears to be a blank page with /implicit/callback in the address bar.  My goal is to be able to write custom logic at this point, which will redirect my user to a fallback/older version of our new application.  Where would I provide such logic without breaking the success path?

Note:  I'm using the OKTA React library (https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa/react/handle-callback/)

Note:  I need to be able to write custom logic as the URL I redirect to will be dependent on a few things

Answer (score 1):

Check Okta's example https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react/tree/master/custom-login

They have a landing page after login, which can process the information received during the authentication process. You can alter it to verify, if a user has a proper claim, to make a decision about redirecting them to your fallback information